# How to get the height of paragraph element of specific class element (js / jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I want to get the height of the paragraph element inside a class element.

For example my html code:

```
<div class="myClass">
    <p> here goe's some awesome text </p>
</div>

<div class="myClass">
    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
    <p>another great text</p>
</div>
```

Now i want to get access to the total height of the div element, but also want to get access to the height of the child element p.

I tried with `getElementsByClassName('myClass').children('p')`, but that doesn't work.
I want to set the height of the div with jQuery, on document ready the height should be the height of div-element minus the height of the divs p element.

Something like:

```
var divs = $(document).getElementsByClassName('myClass');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    divs[i].style.height = divs[i].height() - divs[i].children('p').height();
}
```

I'm not sure how the actual correct code would look like, or if there is even a way to get the height of the child p element.

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery you can search for the `p` inside each `myClass` element. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myClass').each(function(){
        var h = $(this).find('p').height();
        alert(h)
    })
})
```

Check this **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zx58xgu8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this simple , Using **[`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)** jquery method with callback function

```js
$('.myClass').css('height', function(i, v) {
  return parseInt(v, 10) - parseInt($(this).children('p').height(), 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
  <p>here goe's some awesome text</p>
</div>

<div class="myClass">
  <h1>Some Heading</h1>
  <p>another great text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and go as below.

```
$('.myClass > p').each(function(  ) {
    alert($(this).height());
});
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use `outerHeight(true)` to include and padding and/or margin that the container has.

```
$(function() { // Wait for page to load
  $('.myClass').each(function() { // Loop over all items
     var div = $(this),
       height = div.outerHeight(true), // Get height + margin + padding
       paragraphHeight = div.find('p').outerHeight(true); // Get height + margin + padding of P child

    div.height(height - paragraphHeight); // Set the new height
  });
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b9tcxxks/

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the working demo
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/qzvfswz8/66/

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){
$height_div = $(this).height();
$height_p = $(this).find('p').height(); 
$(this).css('height',$height_div-$height_p);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `height` method with `outerHeight` to calculate height of the `p`:

```js
$('.myClass').height(function(i, oldHeight) {
    return parseInt(oldHeight) - $(this).find('p').outerHeight(true)
});
```

```css
.myClass {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #EEE;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <p>here goe's some awesome text</p>
</div>

<div class="myClass">    
    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
    <p>another great text</p>
</div>
```